# custom props doesn't work in material-ui components

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

i want to add ( background & color ) custom props, to the mui button, like this:

```
<ButtonCustom bg="#6415ff" color="#f7fafc">Sign Up</ButtonCustom>
<ButtonCustom bg="#e2e8f0" color="#4a5568">Search</ButtonCustom>
```

file: ButtonCustom.js

```
import Button from "@mui/material/Button";
import { styled } from "@mui/system";
const ButtonStyled = styled(Button)`
  background-color: ${({ bg }) => bg};
  color: ${({ color }) => color};
  padding: 16px 0;
  &:hover {
    background-color: #5011cc;
  }
  font-size: 16px;
  width: 12rem;
`;

export default ButtonStyled;
```

But it will give me this error:

```
TypeError
Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'main')
```

so my question is : how can i add more than one custom props??

Thank you very much for giving me time and answering this question.

Comment: you can't use `color` on props because this the name that `mui` use on the button so use another name like `mycolor`

Comment: opps, thank you so much  you right, i change the prop name, and it's work correctly , thank you so much